# SQLAlchemy: rollback and detect changes during test

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

I want to create dependency override for get_db for my integration tests in FastAPI project, that detects if something was changed and revert all the changes made by the test.

this is my `conftest.py`:

```py
from app import app

engine = create_engine(DB_URL)
TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine
)

def override_get_db():
    try:
        database = TestingSessionLocal()
        yield database
    finally:
        database.close()


app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_client():
    db = override_get_db().__next__()
    with TestClient(app) as client: #There is db init in main function
        additional_db_init(db) # special additional init for tests

# I want to revert the changes after test, so another tests start with the same db
# And detect, if something was changed during test
def test_add_item(test_client):
    response = test_client.post(url="/item",...)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is start a separate transaction for each test, rolling back after:

```py
def override_get_db():
    connection = engine.connect()

    # begin a non-ORM transaction
    transaction = connection.begin()

    # bind an individual Session to the connection
    db = Session(bind=connection)

    yield db

    db.close()
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
```

For more details, see [this tutorial](https://dev.to/jbrocher/fastapi-testing-a-database-5ao5).

Comment: what is `Session` ? Is it the `TestingSessionLocal` or `from sqlalchemy.orm import Session`?

Comment: Sorry if that's unclear, in this case, it's `from sqlalchemy.orm import Session`, since we're creating a separate session which is not bound directly to the engine, but to a separate non-ORM transaction. That is the key that makes this work, it makes any calls to `db.commit()` not actually commit the transaction, which allows us to roll it back between each test.